# Como guardo el valor de un diccionario en una variable con mismo nombre que su key

Tags: python, pandas, diccionarios

quiero guardar el valor de un diccionario donde sus valores son df con el mismo nombre que su key, o sea, df_1 = d['df_1']

```
  import pandas as pd
 
d = {'df_1':pd.DataFrame( [{'col1':['A','B'],'col2':['7','20','300']}]),
 'df_2':pd.DataFrame ([{'a':['A','j'],'b':['7','20','300']}]),
 'df_3':pd.DataFrame ([{'hola':['hola','B'],'YO':['7','20','300']}])}
```

como lo puedo hacer mediante un bucle/ función para que me cree todas las variables (df_1,df_2,df_3) con los nombres de los key asociado a su df.
intente lo siguiente pero guarda el df con nombre k

```
for k,v in d.items():
   k = v
```

desde ya gracias, saludos...

Comment: no puedes, si tu haces un `print(d["df_1"])` obtienes los datos pero con bastantes espacios y si usas `exec()` te daría un error por sintaxis inválida

Comment: se me ocurre una forma *rara* de hacerlo pero tendría que investigar un poco

Comment: @Christian intente con exec() y me sucede lo que comentas,  no encuentro forma de hacerlo, me supero... desde ya agradezco tu colaboración...

Comment: no he encontrado documentación a cerca de los métodos y atributos de la clase `DataFrame` para poder redefinir su *dunder method*, tengo otra forma de hacerlo, voy a probar...

Comment: hice una respuesta, lo siento por la demora, justo chocó con la cena :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por ahora considero imposible o muy difícil lo que deseas, pues si queremos crear variables se tendría que usar la función `exec()` pero el problema radica en como esta definido el método mágico (*dunder method*) `__repr__()` de la clase `DataFrame`. He leído la documentación de pandas pero no proporciona los datos de cuales son sus métodos y atributos de su clase, por lo que sin ello considero imposible. Sin embargo hay una forma de hacer lo que quieres pero modificando el diccionario `d` para que quede así:

```py
d = {'df_1': [{'col1':['A','B'],'col2':['7','20','300']}],
 'df_2':[{'a':['A','j'],'b':['7','20','300']}],
 'df_3':[{'hola':['hola','B'],'YO':['7','20','300']}]}
```

Una vez teniendo esto ya podemos trabajar, lo primer será crear cada variable y asignarle el valor que tiene en el diccionario, esto se hace con la función `exec`, para esto creamos un `for` que itere en el diccionario.

```py
for k,v in d.items():
    exec(f"{k}={v}")
```

Ahora aquí ya viene algo un poco más complicado, pues tendremos que acceder al diccionario global de variables de python. En este lugar se almacenan todas las variables, definiciones, funciones y datos que hayamos creado a lo largo de la ejecución del script. Nuestro trabajo será acceder a este diccionario, buscar la variable y modificar su valor. Para acceder al diccionario de variables globales usamos la función `globals()` que nos devuelve todo, lo único que tendríamos que hacer es buscar la variable y asignarle un nuevo valor.

Si hacemos `print(globals()["df_1"])` obtendremos `[{'col1': ['A', 'B'], 'col2': ['7', '20', '300']}]` y nosotros queremos cambiar este valor, por lo que tendremos que hacer `globals()["df_1"] = nuevo_valor`. Hacemos esto:

```py
globals()["df_1"] = pd.DataFrame(globals()["df_1"])
```

Que sería lo mismo que hacer:

```py
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(d["df_1"])
```

Y esto tendremos que repetirlo para cada una de las variables creadas, por ello lo meteremos dentro del `for`

```py
for k,v in d.items():
    exec(f"{k}={v}")
    globals()[k] = pd.DataFrame(globals()[k])
```

Pero podemos simplificar esto `pd.DataFrame(globals()[k])` no necesitamos acceder nuevamente al diccionario para coger el valor, simplemente utilizamos la variable `v` y listo!

```py
for k,v in d.items():
    exec(f"{k}={v}")
    globals()[k] = pd.DataFrame(v)
```

Ahora si hacemos `print(df_1)` obtendremos el resultado esperado. Lo único malo de aquí es el uso de `exec()` pero.... como la función `globals()` retorna un diccionario, también podemos agregar nuevos datos como lo haríamos con un diccionario `dict[nuevo] = valor` y con esto nos olvidamos del uso de `exec()`.

```py
for k,v in d.items():
    globals()[k] = pd.DataFrame(v)
```

Y de igual forma nos funciona!

### Sorpresa

Peroo... aún hay más, usando `globals()` si podemos usar el diccionario original ^_^.

```py
d = {'df_1':pd.DataFrame( [{'col1':['A','B'],'col2':['7','20','300']}]),
 'df_2':pd.DataFrame ([{'a':['A','j'],'b':['7','20','300']}]),
 'df_3':pd.DataFrame ([{'hola':['hola','B'],'YO':['7','20','300']}])}

for k,v in d.items():
    globals()[k] = v

print(df_1)
```

Y claramente funcionará igual!, por lo que retracto lo que dije al principio, **no es imposible**!

Comment: excelente @Christian funciona perfecto!!! sola una consulta, ocupo el IDE Spyder y cuando hago print(df_1) me dice Undefined name df_1,  PERO  lo corre igual ok, en el explorador de variables veo las  variables df_1 ,df_2, df_3  cargadas ok, solo me arroja ese error que no estan definidas las variables pero SI están creadas! no se porque me las toma como NO definidas!.. desde ya muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: recuerda que debes hacer el `print()` despues del `for` donde se crean las variables, no utilizo spyder por lo que no puedo reproducir tu error, pero al ejecutarlo todo me sale bien. No creo que haya mucho de que preocuparse si puedes ver que las variables han sido creadas correctamente ^_^.